# Getting the EC curve of a EC public key in CNG

Tags: openssl, elliptic-curve, cng

I have a Public key in `CNG (BCRYPT_KEY_HANDLE)`, and I need to know the curve it uses. I tried `BCryptGetProperty with BCRYPT_ALGORITHM_NAME` parameter, but it only gives `ECDH_P256` back, not the exact curve type. I need to know if its `prime256v1 or secp256k1 or secp256r1` curve, because they aren't compatible with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [RFC 4492](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4492): - "Appendix A. Equivalent Curves (Informative)".

`NIST P-256` is also known as `secp256r1` and `prime256v1`.

`ECDH_P256` is therefore `prime256v1` & `P-256` & `secp256r1`!
They are all the same.

`secp256k1` is a different curve entirely, used most notably in Bitcoin.

Comment: This isn't true. If you checkout the RFC you can see, that secp256r1 and prime256v1 are the same, but secp256k1 are different from them. The question was to get information by using CNG about the curve of the key. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: @ZsoltCzikó that was a typo! Fixed! - thanks for highlighting my error :)

Comment: @ZsoltCzikó as your key is `P256` you can be assured its using the `secp256r1` curve.